# Access limitation on video streaming

Tags: video, video-streaming

I understand the basic idea behind video streaming but what I don't understand is if there is a limitation on how many processes can access a file (video file), should there be a limitation also on how many users can watch the video? If yes, then how to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean is there a limit to how many client devices can access a server which provides a video stream, then the answer will depend on the architecture.

If the video is hosted on a single streaming server which has a limit to the number of connections it can serve, or which simply slows down and becomes unresponsive if there are too many clients accessing it, then yes there will be some limit which you may have to find via testing.

More often, especially for any commercial streaming service, the video will be hosted on an 'origin server' which connects to a CDN which in turn delivers the video to the end user.

A CDN, Content Delivery Network, will typically cache popular content near the edge of the network which will both improve access time for users, and also mean that there are actually multiple copies of your original video at different 'edges' of the CDN.

For large CDN providers, the limit on current users or streams will typically not be any system or architecture bottle necks, but there may be commercial limits depending on the business agreement or account limits that are set up.

Comment: Thank you Mick. But if the video source and the viewers are in the same country, how can CDN help?

Comment: @ZarulZakuan - CDN's are used within countries as well as globally. If there is no CDN then it may be simply a case of specifying your streaming server to support the number of direct connections you need. Most commercial streaming server will have som configuration information around this.

Comment: I see. What would be the alternative of CDN? setting up our own LB or reverse proxy using nginx for example?

Comment: @ZarulZakuan - the easiest alternative is to simply not use a CDN and test how the service is, if that is practical for your case. If not then you may want to look at a dedicated video streaming server like Wowza, or Unified - there will have details on scaling and be designed to handle the configured load.